# Look up object keys by value

Tags: javascript, object, inverse

```
Object = {"o":"s","e":"w"}
```

If I have this object, is there a way to perform reverse lookups on it?
Something like:

```
Object.invert()["s"]
> "o"
```

Comment: For what reason you want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to revert the key/value mapping.

```
var test = {a: "b", c: "d"}
var reverted = {}
for(var key in test) {
    reverted[test[key]] = key
}
```